# Pipelight Silverlight not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, wine, pipelight

I installed pipelight and try to enable silverlight with

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

And receive the message "Plugin silverlight5.1 is now enabled". But when I go to this page http://fds-team.de/pipelight/ with Firefox, the test is failed for silverlight. In about:plugins, there is no mention of silverlight whatsoever.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running "sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have the user agent overrider for firefox search and install it under the add-ons in firefox. I use mine on windows/firefox 29 option

ensure that after running:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

you need to run the following after accepting the licence agreement

```
touch $HOME/.config/wine-wininet-installer.accept-license
```

Close firefox if open (very important)
then in a terminal window run

```
Sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove old pipelight:

`sudo apt-get remove pipelight`

Now install:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
 sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Install silverlight plugin:

`sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight`

**Before proceeding, it's strongly recommended to close your web browser. Without doing this, the plugin may fail to install or crash the browser**

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the exact same issue. Silverlight plugin did not show up in Firefox right after installing and enabling.

It seems the installer already enables Silverlight and a manual command does not really change that. All I had to do was disable Silverlight and enable it again:

> sudo pipelight-plugin --disable silverlight
>
> sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight

Enabling the plugin again asks to accept 2 licenses. Do accept them, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a professional in Ubuntu but able to successfully run my pipelight-plugin in my firefox.

Go to this website http://fds-team.de/pipelight/ and find out what is the problem with the browser.

If its **user agent** related problem then download a useragent switching addon like *User Agent Switcher*,*User Agent Changer*  etc and switch it to windows platform.

Else if the problem is related to installation of silverlight in your ubuntu then

**close the browser** and update the plugin

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

and retest with http://fds-team.de/pipelight/

if problem persists then try to disable and reenable pipelight

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --disable silverlight

sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this also. Instead of :
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight  # I used the more times than I care to think about with no results.

I did :
pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight

I have absolutely no idea of why but it worked where the sudo addition did not.